# ffmpeg scaling nvenc maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: ffmpeg, nvenc

I want to fully hw transcode mkv files to mp4 and up- /downscale the content maintaning the aspect ratio.

With CPU based transcoding you just add:

```
scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease
```

With HW (CUDA) transcoding either `-resize` on Decoding side or `-scale_npp` on encoding side is possible but both dont seem to be capable to force original acpect ratio.

I want to for instance upscale 1920x800 file to 1920x1080 while filling the rest with black bars so I can overlay subtitles over the bars for instance...

With this i can fully transcoding using GPU power reather than utilizing cpu. any ideas?

Comment: Nothing in this world grinds my gears more than video files with added black padding (on any edge). Most modern displays are wide (both computer monitors and mobile phones), so padding (especially on the top or bottom) means the video will end up with large black bars on all sides. On phones this makes them effectively unwatchable. Also, every video player ever is capable of adding black padding where necessary to fill the display, and then showing available subtitles on top of that black area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With scale_npp, you can implement `force_original_aspect_ratio` manually.

Assuming your max size is 1920x1080,

it would be

```
scale_npp=w='if(gt(a\,1920/1080)\,1920\,oh*a)':h='if(gt(a\,1920/1080)\,ow/a\,1080)'
```

However, neither scale nor scale_npp will pad the input. That requires use of the s/w pad filter.

Comment: what do you mean by pad?

Comment: *while filling the rest with black bars* --> that's called padding

Comment: Aah understood, that confirms my question, making its impossible to use pure hw. I mixed hw with sw now makes the encoding 8x faster than pure sw so I am happy

Comment: @Sambir could you show a command example with `scale_npp` and `pad` filters mixing?